# phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner (Data matrix) issue with iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Using phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner format of Data Matrix working perfect in Android, but when I scan using iOS its not working with some formats alone.

When I scan with QR image contains values like 1309 it is showing some garbage values. At the same time when the QR image is big it is working perfect. Is there any QR image size restriction for iOS?

Comment: Its not specific to values like 1309. It is not working randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Created a custom plugin using ZXingObjC is working fine.

https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC

I guess it is bug in phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner plugin.